# Dynamically change the <source> element of a video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have created a game using html, css and javascript only, I am trying, every time the game ends, to play a video. I have these videos in a folder, and they are named "video1.mp4", "video2.mp4", etc.
So I thought of creating the `<source>` element of the `<video>` element dynamically, but I guess I am doing something wrong. Any clues?

```
<div id="videoBox">
  <video id="idVideo" width="320px" height="176px">
    <script>
    var newEle = document.createElement("source"); //creates <source> element

    var changingSource = '"videos/video' + counter + '.MP4"';
    // the previous line creates the names of the video files using a variable (counter)
    newEle.src = changingSource; //uses those names
    newEle.type = "video/mp4"; //defines type of file
    var ele = document.getElementById("idVideo"); //handle to the video element
    ele.appendChild(newEle); //appending the <source> to the <video> element
    </script>
  </video>
</div>
<br>
```

And then, inside a function that runs when the game ends:

```
var videoVar = document.getElementById(idVideo); //the previous line gets a handle to the video file

videoVar.play(); //starts playing the video
```

Comment: write `changingSource = 'videos/video' + counter + '.MP4'` instead of `changingSource = '"videos/video' + counter + '.MP4"'`.

Comment: What are the extra quotes around changingSource for?  have you tried it without them?

Comment: Thanks to both of you, you were right. Also the handle to the video was missing the quotes, i.e. instead of var videoVar = document.getElementById(idVideo);   I should have written var videoVar = document.getElementById("idVideo");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using quotes inside quotes on the following line of code:

```
var changingSource = '"videos/video' + counter + '.MP4"';
```

Try to change that to the following:

```
var changingSource = 'videos/video' + counter + '.MP4';
```

Of course you will need to have a counter variable which keeps track of the video you want to play, but I guess you have that sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I additional suggest you put the source element in your HTML,then you need to change it's src property and play it every time when the game ends.
you must noticed that the appending source only runs one time in you document.